# My ViewController's View Isn't Appearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a table view controller with custom derived cells. When somebody clicks a button in the cell (the editButton below), I want to load a different view controller to display a pop up dialog.

I created a xib and view controller, and loaded the new VC that way, but everything in the new VC object was nil, and the new VC didn't appear.

I then tried programaticaly creating the view, using the initWithDefaultText:origin: initializer, but it still doesn't appear, but the member widgets are now valid.

Am I missing something?

MyListTableViewCell.h

```
@interface MyListTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <MyEditQueryDelegate>
...
```

MyListTableViewCell.m

```
@implementation MyListTableViewCell

+ (MyListTableViewCell *)loadFromNibWithItem:(MyListItem *)item
  expandHandler:(MyItemExpandHandler)handler
  controller:(MyListViewController*)controller
{
    MyListTableViewCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]
        loadNibNamed:@"MyListTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.item = item;
    cell.expandHandler = handler;
    cell.queryLabel.text = item.displayText;
    [cell hideOptions];

    [cell.editButton addTarget: cell action: @selector(editButtonTapped:)
        forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    return cell;
}

- (void) editButtonTapped: (UIButton*) sender
{
    CGPoint globalOrigin = [self.superview convertPoint:self.frame.origin toView:nil];
    NSLog(@"editButtonTapped Point (%f, %f).", globalOrigin.x, globalOrigin.y);
    // This log message appears.
    // MyEditQueryViewController* vc = [[MyEditQueryViewController alloc]
    //      initWithNibName:@"MyEditQueryView" bundle:nil];
    // This resulted in a nil view in the vc and no visual change.
    MyEditQueryViewController* vc = [[MyEditQueryViewController alloc]
        initWithDefaultText:[self.queryLabel text] orign:globalOrigin];

    vc.delegate = self;
    [_controller presentViewController: vc animated: YES completion: nil];
    // vc should appear here????
}
```

MyEditQueryViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyEditQueryDelegate.h"

@interface MyEditQueryViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id<MyEditQueryDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView* editView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* cancelButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton* saveButton;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
- (id)initWithDefaultText:(NSString*)defaultText orign:(CGPoint)origin;

- (IBAction)cancelTapped:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)saveTapped:(id)sender;
@end
```

MyEditQueryViewController.m

```
@implementation MyEditQueryViewController 
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSLog(@"initWithNibName:bundle:");
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self)
    {
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithDefaultText:(NSString*)defaultText orign:(CGPoint)origin
{
    NSLog(@"initWithDefaultText:origin:");
    self = [super initWithNibName: nil bundle:nil];
    if (self)
    {
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenRect];

        UIImage* smokeGlass = [UIImage imageNamed:@"SmokeGlass.png"];
        UIImageView* background = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:smokeGlass];
        [self.view addSubview:background];

        CGRect editViewFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, origin.y, screenRect.size.width, 122.0);
        _editView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:editViewFrame];
        [self.view addSubview: _editView];

        CGRect textViewFrame = CGRectMake(20.0, 20.0, 280.0, 30.0);
        _textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame: textViewFrame];
        _textField.text = defaultText;
        [_editView addSubview: _textField];

        CGRect cancelButtonFrame = CGRectMake(20.0, 72.0, 50.0, 30.0);
        _cancelButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:cancelButtonFrame];
        _cancelButton.titleLabel.text = @"Cancel";
        [_cancelButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancelTapped:)
                forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_editView addSubview: _cancelButton];

        CGRect saveButtonFrame = CGRectMake(266.0, 72.0, 34.0, 30.0);
        _saveButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:saveButtonFrame];
        _saveButton.titleLabel.text = @"Save";
        [_saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveTapped:)
              forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [_editView addSubview: _saveButton];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `_controller` when you call `_controller presentViewController`?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yeah...I'm that dumb. I never set the controller property. I'm still not used to the idea of being able to call messages on nil without getting an error. Good catch!

Comment: Add action for your button in cellForRowAtIndexpath and in the action method present your view controller. Hope It would work.